# Change button background on click event , notification bar

Tags: android, notifications

i want to Change button background on click event , notification bar

for eg. i have button with text play which is on notification bar when i click on play it should be change to pause and again if i click on pause this pause text should be changed to play text, how can we do it any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

it is more like music player has on going notification so we can play and pause the media using notification bar as well.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    RemoteViews contentv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification_bar);

    int icon = R.drawable.noti_launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "notification";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // now
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    notification.contentView = contentv;
    Intent laucherIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);

    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

    PendingIntent launcherPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            laucherIntent, 0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    Intent flaotIntent = new Intent(this, FloatMainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent floatPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, flaotIntent,
            0);

    PendingIntent wifiPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(Constants.ACTION_WIFI), 0);
    PendingIntent btPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(
            Constants.ACTION_BLUETOOTH), 0);
    PendingIntent mobileDataPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(Constants.ACTION_DATA), 0);
    PendingIntent alarmsPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(Constants.CUSTOM_ACTION), 0);
            contentv.setImageViewResource(R.id.bluetooth, R.drawable.noti_wifi);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bluetooth, btPI);
    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wifi, wifiPI);
    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.data, mobileDataPI);
    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.alarm, pi);
    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.icon, launcherPI);
    contentv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.float_notification, floatPI);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? and also please post some code so that we can help you with it

Comment: i have tried contentv.setImageViewResource method but when clicked on button

Comment: We cannot help you if you just explain us in text format, post some code so that we can identify where its  not working and why

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change icons in ActionBar dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006749/change-icons-in-actionbar-dynamically)

Comment: in the above code i want when i click on bluetooth button then the background image of that button should be changed
what i mean is when blueooth is on then it should have a bt_on background image else bt_off image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        contentv.setInt(R.id.viewId, "change", R.drawable.nextId);
```

you can use this for change background image.