# Programmatically change ActionBar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm coming back to my main activity from a fragment and for some logic I have to change the appearence of an icon on the action bar menu.

This is the menu on the action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="it.gn.sfa.Main">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:title="Search" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter_empty"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Filter" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="New" />

</menu>
```

I have to change the sencond item (the one with id = `action_filter`).
I've tried different solutions, found on different post. The most rated is

```
mOptionsMenu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_filter));
```

but seems not to work.

On the other side `getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_filter));` changes the logo, and I don't want so.

How can i change only the second item on menu?

Comment: Can you post all the code related with the mOptionsMenu? Specifically, when and how you are instantiating this mOptionsMenu variable

Comment: I instantiate mOptionsMenu in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu): mOptionsMenu = menu.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28478791/1038702

Answer (score 20):

try this one

```
mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter);
```

Assuming you have it all set up for `mOptionsMenu` in

```
private Menu mOptionsMenu;
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // inflating your menu here
    mOptionsMenu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: mOptionsMenu is used right in that way. But after that line I inflate a different layout. Is that a problem?

Comment: Just tried and mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter); gives me a nullPointerException.

Comment: hmm, post your npe here, cause my answer worked for me, i tested it in my own test case.

Comment: I've posted everything [here](https://gist.github.com/dfcd2d91b40189b0868b.git). Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will be help for you

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>" + "Messages" + "</font>"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.messagebar_color)));
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_arrow_black);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)**

I changed the color of my search bar programmatically. I am posting the code here. Hope it helps.

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getTintedDrawable(R.drawable.search, R.color.blue));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Where **getTintedDrawable()** is a function that i created which returns a drawable. So all you need to do is replace `getTintedDrawable(R.drawable.search, R.color.blue)` by your drawable.

**NOTE:** I have used `menu.getItem(0)` my code since I had only 1 item defined in menu/items.xml. If you have multiple try different values (from 0 to one less than number of menu items). My guess would be that its the number at which the item is defined but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to rotate/change the icon this way:

```
MenuItem item = getToolbar().getMenu().findItem(Menu.FIRST);
<prepare the image view from drawable here>
item.setActionView(imageView);
```

Seems to work OK.
You could also simply use the `item.setIcon()` instead.