# how to show an image view in bottom navigation [Android]

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am learning bottom navigation view in android i can show a set of predefined icons in bottom navigation view but i do not know how to show an image that is download at runtime in it instead of an icon

Comment: do you mean you want to show non-drawable image from server?

Comment: Please do some R&D first before you ask something, That shows you efforts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116247/load-a-remote-image-in-a-menuitem-using-glide - check this question

Comment: it is actually the same problem but doesn't solve mine