# Actionbar icons not beeing updated

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change an icon in the actionbar, but I can not get it work. If I send to the log the getIcon().toString(), It seems that the icon is modified, but the actionbar is not updated.

This is the main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The menu xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:orderInCategory="110"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:title="Connect"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
    android:orderInCategory="130"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/testin"
    android:title="Test_in"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_testin"
    android:orderInCategory="120"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And the main activity code:

```
//Menu Items
MenuItem testinMenu, connectMenu;
Menu actionMenu;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Action Bar
    toolbar = findViewById( R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menumain, menu);
    actionMenu = menu;
    connectMenu = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.connect);
    testinMenu = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.testin);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.connect: {

            connectMenu.setIcon( R.drawable.ic_stop);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            if( isRainbowConnected == false) {
                connect();
            } else
                disconnect();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.testin: {
            if( isRainbowConnected == true)
                sendTestIn();
            break;
        }


        // case blocks for other MenuItems (if any)
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to change the actionbar icon or action bar option menu icon. because  after looking your code it seems like your trying to change the actionbar menu icon

Comment: Sorry,... the actionbar menu icon.!

Comment: You can use `invalidateOptionsMenu` (if you're using an `Activity`) in order to recreate the `ActionBar` menu.

Comment: follow this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006749/change-icons-in-actionbar-dynamically

Comment: I do call invalidateOptionsMenu, but nothing is modified.

Comment: Solved overwriting method onPrepareOptionsMenu. Thanks!!